# Total time elapsed between multiple timestamps

Tags: excel, select, time, formula

I have a lot data of transactions for different users such as

[image: example table]

and I need a formula/quick way to calculate the total elapsed time for each user
e.g.

```
 user A total time 08:35 - 08:07 = 00:28 
 user B total time 11:00 - 10:09 = 00:51
```

I am able to select the first time stamp for each user using VLOOKUP but am unable to select the last timestamp to calculate the difference

Answer (score 1):

Use MAXIFS and MINIFS

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,"A")-MINIFS(B:B,A:A,"A")
```

---

If one has an older version on Excel that does not have those formula then AGGREGATE will suffice:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,B2:B19/(A2:A19="A"),1)-AGGREGATE(15,7,B2:B19/(A2:A19="A"),1)
```